# What is the opposite of backdating?

Tags: antonyms

If I take a record and adjust its time to the past, I *backdate* it. Is there an equivalent term for adjusting its time to the future? Fordating?

Comment: How about "postdating"?

Comment: Predicting perhaps?

Comment: @HotLicks - That's a valid answer; you should post it as such.

Comment: *Predating*? Not to be confused with predator.

Comment: I think you should be careful about assuming ***backdate*** is a reasonable way to describe changing a date on a (computer-based?) record to some earlier date. The term is already in use for contexts such as *His pay rise was backdated to three months earlier* - which simply means he would receive (additional) ***back pay*** for those three months in his next pay check, because his salary was *retrospectively* adjusted (cf *retrospective legislation*, generally thought to be a very bad thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cheques/checks it is called [post-dating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-dated_cheque).